# Binding not working for error validation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have style for validation error of a control .I show the error in tooltip also I want to show it in a Textblock next to control.The binding in tooltip works fine but its doesnt work with textblock.I tried hardcoding some text in textblock it works ,but binding is not working.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="S_ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="Red" 
                      FontSize="12pt" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent,
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" >
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="myControl"/>
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
            Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Maroon"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I think problem is with type of ErrorContent property, it is showing of type object and Text required I think string so try to convert errorcontent to string in binding

Comment: Same works fine with the tooltip binding, but it doesn't work with text block.